# Segmenting objects of similar intensity from an image

Tags: python, c++, image-processing, image-segmentation

I am working on segmentation of medical images (specifically CT scans) in Python and C++. I have managed to successfully eliminate bone, air, and fat from the slices using a combination of thresholding, region growing, and morphological operators. The main problem that is left is segmenting vital organs from muscles, since they have very similar intensities and often abut one another.

For example, in the image below, a piece of bowel is seen abutting abdominal wall muscle:

[image]

The desired segmentation result is as follows:

[image]

Another acceptable segmentation is as follows:

[image]

My question is: what segmentation algorithm should I be using to achieve one of the desired segmentation results? So far, I have tried:

- Thresholding: does not work because the two regions are too similar in intensity.
- Region growing: does not work because the regions to be segmented are "connected".
- Canny filter: fails to find edges at large values of sigma, disconnected edges at lower values of sigma.
- Watershed transform: results in severely over-segmented images. No clear criterion to merge regions.
- Active contours: fails to find an appropriate boundary between the two objects.

Any pointers are appreciated.

---

**Thresholding filter**

[image]

**Canny filter**

[image]

**Watershed transform**

[image]

Comment: Perhaps by shape? The blue shape appears to have darker regions than the top elongated one as well. Maybe something as simple as contrast enhancement of mid-level gray and then some of the above mentioned processes again?

Comment: Hi, did you find any solutions for this?
If yes then Kindly post in the answer section and mark it as the accepted answer. I am facing a similar kind of problem. Would help a great deal.

Answer (score 1):

I think that extracting the edge between these objects would solve the problem. Since the edge on the image can be seen and is thus distingushable for human, I would try to apply a **high-pass filter/gradient detection** in order to sharpen the edges as a pre-processing step before trying any other algorithms. After that maybe some **dilation/erosion** to close the objects' edges or delete unnecessary garbage and **flood fill** as a next step will do the work.

Another option is **Hough transform** - it might be able to extract that edge as it is able to extract subtle features (example from Mathworks: http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/detect-lines-in-images.html).

You can also try a **variation of thresholding** - divide the image into **subsets** (squares) and calculate a coefficient for each subset based on the grey level of the pixels it contains (e.g. a mean grey level). Since one of these objects is slightly lighter than the other as a whole, it might work - these two objects are locally similar, but different globally. You will have to play with the subset size as well as with the threshold value (i.e. the coefficient value).

EDIT: I've just seen the images you've uploaded. Wouldn't some **dilation** and, after that, **erosion** performed on the result of **Canny with sigma = 1** solve the problem? It would close the edges thus separating the objects - it wouldn't be 100% accurate, but will separate these two areas maintaining the shape more or less.